# Any non-open sourced WYSIWYG editors better than the open sourced ones?

Tags: html, editor, wysiwyg

Normally I use CKEditor when we need an on-line WYSIWYG HTML editors, but we have a project for which the on-line editing component is pretty critical and we have enough of a budget that it makes sense to consider non-open sourced products. We will most likely need to make some modifications to whatever editor we use. I've never surveyed the non-open source WYSIWYG HTML editors, so I'm wondering if anyone here has some suggestions on good ones. Ideally the source code would be available for editing and it would integrate easily with PHP.
Thanks.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it!

Comment: If a product is open source, doesn't mean it isn't any good... IMO CKEditor is one of the best WYSIWYG I've tried. (Look at the Linux OS, it's free, open source, and arguably the best OS out there)

Answer (score 2):

I think that companies like IBM, Oracle and Adobe have enough money to license whatever editor they want to use in their products, and the fact is that they are using CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/who-is-using-ckeditor

So maybe it would better to spend that money supporting CKEditor with a license and helping that way to improve the tool that you are already used to.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> ...to consider non-open sourced products...

and

> ...likely need to make some modifications...

These two statements are in contradiction. I'd consider it unlikley that you'd be allowed to make modifications to a closed source product.

Additionally, the bulk of code in virtually all web-based WYSIWYG HTML editors is Javascript, so is effectively open source by default, since the software is served as source code to every web browser that views the page.

Because of this, any closed source product that doesn't want to be pirated is almost certain to have its Javascript code heavily encrypted and/or obfuscated, which will definitely be problematic for you if you need to make modifications to it.

There is however, a third option which may work for you:  There are some which offer a commercial licence **as well as** an open source licence.

An example of this is the [SPAW Editor](http://spaweditor.com/), and it is in fact quite a good product. The commercial licence allows you to modify the source without having to redistribute your code, which is a big plus point for some companies. Sadly it seems to have stalled in development a couple of years ago, so it isn't going to be as good as some of the more up-to-date alternatives, but it may still be worth investigating if that licensing option sounds like the kind of thing you need. You can even download it under their open source licence to see if it's any good, and buy the commercial licence afterward if you like it.